# Storing HTML snippets with Python

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I'm scrapping pages using Beautiful Soup and I would like to save some html snippets offline and use them to compare with every time I scrape again to check if there as been any change to the page .

Aside from directly writing out an html file, what would be the best strategy for save a lot of html snippets offline ( which format ) for comparison use later on ?

Thank you

Comment: If you don't need the HTML file itself, just compare the code, then use a database.

Comment: If you only want to know if a change has been made (but don't care about the specifics of the change) then you can hash the scraped data (for example, as an MD5 sum) and store/compare the hashes.

Answer (score 2):

This is a classic use for a [`hash function`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function).  Algorithms like `md5` and `sha256` boil any amount of text down to a few bytes.  You can store just the  hashes for any file you parse, and then when you get a new file, calculate the hash of that and compare the two hashes.